# MySQL Naming conventions

Tags: mysql, sql, django

I'm recreating this database (that I had originally made from django modelw) on an Amazon EC2 instance. I used MySQL workbench to translate the database into a mockup, and then had it forward-engineer it to all the CREATE statements in a .sql file. However some of the foreign key stuff is named really strangely, and I'm not sure what parts I can take out or rename and what parts are necessary. Here's a sample of the code that I'm talking about.

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `gamelydb`.`quotes` (
`id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,   
`game_id` INT(11) NOT NULL ,   
`quotetext` VARCHAR(400) NOT NULL ,   
`speaker_id` INT(11) NOT NULL ,   
PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,   
INDEX `quotes_7b333d1e` (`game_id` ASC) ,   
INDEX `quotes_7171bad0` (`speaker_id` ASC) , 
CONSTRAINT `game_id_refs_id_274910a8`
        FOREIGN KEY (`game_id` )
        REFERENCES `gamelydb`.`game` (`id` ),   
CONSTRAINT `speaker_id_refs_id`
        FOREIGN KEY (`speaker_id` )
        REFERENCES `gamelydb`.`person` (`id` )) 
ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;
```

So like where it has "INDEX 'quotes_randomstuff'" or 'speaker_id_refs_id', do I need all the random stuff or what should I rename it to for clarity's/practicality's sake?

Comment: MySQL requires a unique name for each key. If you don't provide one, it'll generate one for you, hence the 'garbage' in the key name. You can change those if you want, but unless you're manipulating keys frequently, is it worth the time/effort?

Comment: Ok sounds good. I don't think the internal game_id will be changed ever, so it probably isn't worth it for this case. Thanks

Comment: @Marc B - you should have put that as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) you probably need it. It's an ID.

Comment: does having all the INDEXes (there are a lot in the whole file) make a difference/are they necessary?

Comment: indices are only necessary if you plan complex selections on the non-key fields of the table, and you need fast access to certain combintaions of fields. I didn't know what the planned use was, I had assumed that you knew what you needed the indices for.

Comment: I mean I have a grasp of what they are for and such, but they were put in by the mysql workbench conversion. I'll probably just end up taking them out, cause the selections won't be anything complex, nor is speed too vital. Thanks.